# Wordpress WP_Query() Not working properly

Tags: php, wp-query

We would like to know that how we occur error when we implement this code in our sidebar.php

```
$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach($categories as $category) 
{ 
  printf('<h2>%s</h2><ul>', $category->cat_name);
  $posts = new WP_Query('cat='.$category->cat_ID);
  while($posts->have_posts())
  {     
    $posts->the_post();
    echo '<li>', the_title(), '</li>'; 
  }   
  print '</ul>';  
}
```

The error we are getting:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php on line 2374

Answer (score 8):

a possible conflict with the name `$posts` which is used by wp core;
try, for instance:

```
$categories = get_categories();  
foreach($categories as $category)  
{    
  printf('<h2>%s</h2><ul>', $category->cat_name);   
  $cat_posts = new WP_Query('cat='.$category->cat_ID);   
  while($cat_posts->have_posts())   
  {          
    $cat_posts->the_post();     
    echo '<li>', the_title(), '</li>';    
  }      
  print '</ul>';   
}
```

Comment: Great! Not evidently, but $posts is reserved by WP Core.

Answer (score 0):

hi  rodger,

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'Old ID', 'meta_value' => $atts['oldid'] ) );
 return $query['post_title'];
```

[Codex Ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query). you should try this..

Comment: without while loop. replace the total code with this new one . or we have to implement by own. and please also suggest me, how to implement our H1 tags, li tags with this new code .